# Как создаются адреса статей

Tags: php, html

В пример тот же stackoverflow.com/раздел_статей/статья_о_прекрасной_погоде.
Я шаманю сайт на php, знаю вариант с php?id=123, но хотелось бы название транслитом например. Что то мне подсказывает, что создавать ручками для каждой статьи файл с отдельным названием не правильное решение. Подскажите в какую сторону копать?

Answer (score 1):

**Внимание!** Это велосипедные наработки для сайтов без фреймворков и CMS, не отображают множества вещей, являются лишь отправным шагом и я мог что-то упустить/забыть.

В таблицу с вашими статьями добавьте поле url, в котором будет писаться транслит названия (поле должно быть редактируемым в админке), затем настройте ЧПУ в .htaccess

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*) /index.php?query=$1&%{QUERY_STRING} [L]
```

где **query** это параметр, отвечающий за показ ваших страниц, например site.com/index.php?query=about будет преобразован в site.com/about/

Затем на PHP получаем наш query

```
$requestURI=!empty($_GET["query"])?(string)$_GET["query"]:"/";
```

и ищем страницу в БД, обрабатываем прочие GET-параметры и прочее.

Повторюсь, что это велосипед, изучайте опыт фреймворков (хотя их система ЧПУ мне не нравится)

Comment: Спасибо за ответ, теперь знаю куда двигаться!)